# Можно ли восстановить фаил незакоммиченый в git?

Tags: git

Перешел значит я на другой коммит, но к сожалению не сохранил фаил.. Есть ли возможность хоть как нибудь его восстановить? В корзине нету, бэкапы дисков его тоже не видят.

Comment: В stash поищи, а так не должно было переключить ветку без stash или commit измененных файлов

Comment: Покажите все ваши команды, что так произошло. Если делали в командной строке, то история команд должна сохраниться.

Comment: Какой файл? Git не переписывает файлы, которые не в индексе, самостоятельно. Либо изменения переносятся, либо конфликт не даёт перейти на другое изменение. Если речь про изменение, сделанное позже, то смотри `git reflog`.